# How do I connect my python spyder with github?

Tags: python, github, spyder

Is there any way to connect python spyder with github?

I manage my R scripts via github, because R provides with
interfaces that enables users to commit, pull and push,
but I wonder if there is same(or similar) system in python(x,y) spyder.

I want to manage my python scripts with github, not just locally
editing my code and manually write change logs on my hand every time.

Answer (score 39):

A command line git has been integrated into Spyder.

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6105

> First right click the tab corresponding to any file in your repository and click "set console working directory."
>
> Then go to the Ipython window in Spyder and simply type your git commands (assuming Git is installed and its paths are configured properly) but append a "!" to the beginning of your command:
>
> ```
> !git add "file.py"
> !git commit -m "My commit"
> !git push origin master
> ```

Comment: Is there documentation on how the "!" feature works, I cannot find any?

Comment: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html

Comment: @DickMcManus "!" is just the escape character to run shell commands from IPython, c.f., https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html

Answer (score 22):

(*Spyder developer here*) I'm sorry but right now (February 2017) there's no integration between Spyder and Git/Github.

Besides, there are no concrete plans to add this support. We could it in a year or year and a half.

Related issue on github: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/816

Answer (score 11):

+1 @betontalpfa. For me, I wanted to put a local file to an existing Github.com repository through Spyder ipython console.

So, instead of clicking "set console working directory", I just did the following in ipython console within Spyder (I'm on Mac OSX Mojave, and have installed Xcode already from the Appstore):

- Init working directory as a git directory

  ```
  !git init
  ```
- Pull existing repository to merge with files you want to push

  ```
  !git remote add origin https://github.com/myUserName/sample.git
  ```
- Add the file to local git

  ```
  !git add temp.py
  ```
- Push the file to github.com

  ```
  !git push -u origin master
  ```

Comment: I think the answer is fine. Its just using the terminal within Spyder to interact with git.